# In iOS, on tapping X button in google Interstitial ad, black screen is showing with another X button in iPhone X, XS, XR devices

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, admob, interstitial

I am using the below code for presenting interstitial ad in iOS.

```
interstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: AppDelegate.navigationController)
interstitialAd.delegate = self
```

On tapping the X button on the interstitial ad, an ad is dismissing properly except for safe area layout devices.

But for iPhone X, XR, XS devices, the black screen is showing again. Another close button is there on the black screen.

This issue is happening only in iPhone X, XR, XS models only because of the safe area layout.

Does anyone face this issue? Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: What ad network you're using? Why you're showing it on `AppDelegate.navigationController` ?